# Custom Host Header not forwarded by Feign Client

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign, hostheaders

I am trying to send a custom host header using feign client, but the consumer application is not picking them. I am using spring boot feign and not openfeign.

Apart from Host,  everyother header seems to be working as expected.

```
 ResponseEntity<JSONObject> list(@PathVariable("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("modelName") String modelName,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String authorizationHeader,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Host", required = true) String hostName);
```

When i pass hostname as "xyz.com" the consumer application is still taking default host header.

In Consumer code when i read value of Host header from controller class, i do not get zyz.com. instead it picks from dns name.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened for me - the `@Param` and `@Headers` didn't work for the "Host" header.
Two things that I changed solved the issue - use `OkHttpClient`, and add a `requestInterceptor` when building the client:

```
client = Feign.builder()
    .client(new OkHttpClient())
    .requestInterceptor(request -> request.header("Host", hostHeaderValue))
    .target(MyClient.class, url);
```

Comment: Thank you, besides did you try adding the below command in your vm arguments.  I faced the same issue for restTemplate as well for some strange reason and this below helped me out. 

Never got time to try it for  feign

-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true

Answer (score 0):

The solution is included in the springframework. Add in the your property file:

```
feign.okhttp.enabled = true
```

And add the dependency of okhttp3, example in pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can find more informations [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");`
to allow usage of restricted headers

see https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/747